# How to add a video in nuxtjs and load them in the page. Help me pls

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

**Video uploading and Viewing**

I want to upload videos in a page and display or load them in the webpage.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, have you tried to search for a solution or tutorial?

Comment: put your video in your `static` folder and use the <video> element https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

[`@nuxtjs/cloudinary`](https://cloudinary.nuxtjs.org/) is the perfect module for that one and you'll probably not find a better service for a simple upload + optimized serving of both your images and videos.

The [VueJS SDK documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/vue_image_and_video_upload) may also be useful.